# nmap showing open ports despite port close

Tags: iptables

I just set up my iptables with a DROP policy:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p udp -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 115.231.222.176/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

But when I run nmap many port remains open:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
443/tcp   open  https
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11
```

Any idea why?
Does it represent a security breach?

Answer (score 0):

Iptables operates on incoming or outgoing packets by matching the packet against the set of rules of Iptables. It does not have to do anything with whether a port is open or not.

If the `ssh` traffic is blocked via the following rule in `iptables`,

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

then when a packet arrives destined for port 22 will be dropped by the kernel but your computer may actually listening on port 22 because `SSH` daemon is running on port 22.

To close a port you need to stop the service listening on that port. For example to close port 22, the following will do:

```
sudo service ssh stop
```

Comment: OK; that I got it; but with my current iptables all my ports should be close but many ports are still open; why?

Comment: Iptables does not control which port is open or which port is closed, it is the service that is running on that very port....Iptables will just do filtering on traffic based on given rules.

Comment: iptables basically says " You guys can have that port open, but I just won't let you hear what the remote machine is saying". If you want to close ports, kill the processes

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me, try to set your computer on the same network segment as the server in question, port scanning via routers can give you some false results.

If you run nmap (`nmap -v -A yourIP`) from other network segments, ports not opened will be shown with a question (`?`):

```
2000/tcp open   cisco-sccp
```